# Error Installing Tridion 2013 SP1 CMS

Tags: 2013-sp1, installation

We are getting an error installing Tridion CMS. It's a very generic error and we cannot determine how we made wrong.

When we execute the setup file and we inform the oracle information we are getting a null pointer error.

[image]

[image]

We think that the problem is related to Oracle. If we try to configure a MSSQLServer as database, installer is trying to connect to the database(although we don't have any). But, with Oracle option, the error appears immediately.

Do you see this error before?

Thank you.

Comment: Check if your Oracle client is installed or not ? If it is installed then confirm the accessibility of your oracle database server from the CMS server.

Comment: I noticed Sayantan got a similar comment earlier :).. So removing mine..

Comment: You might want to tag this case with your oracle version as well as update the title to make it easier for people to help you

Comment: Any updates on this? Definitely my first impression was: Oracle Client not installed.

Answer (score 2):

These steps are for a brand new install of SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 connecting to an Oracle 12c database:

First you need to make sure you have followed all the steps from the manual in regards to configuring your Oracle database server: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Doracle&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1450779862431&currentQuery=oracle&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-83B77343-A2E0-4114-889D-CF952BC5612C&docid=GUID-83B77343-A2E0-4114-889D-CF952BC5612C&addHistory=true&query=oracle&scope=&tid=8c86575f-aecc-4189-aa0d-96dbe2dfa8ce&filename=GUID-83B77343-A2E0-4114-889D-CF952BC5612C.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false

Next you need to need to ensure you have the correct Oracle client software installed on your Content Manager. The steps are explained here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Doracle&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1450779862431&currentQuery=oracle&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-19199E60-4989-4F63-82AC-92B588A46590&docid=GUID-19199E60-4989-4F63-82AC-92B588A46590&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-19199E60-4989-4F63-82AC-92B588A46590.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false

The ODAC Component that worked great for me was this one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

I downloaded the 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64

You can then install the required items which are Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server and Oracle Data Provider for .NET.

After installing this, configuring your TNSNAMES.ORA file correctly and then restarting your server you should be able to run the Content Manager installer.